# how to lock iphone screen remotely

Tags: iphone, objective-c

how to lock iphone screen remotely ? is this thing possible with a jail break device and normal one device ?

there is application find my iphone from apple it self but can we create our own one , I don't want to put on apple store so no worries for apple rejection.

If this things are possible then any one can suggest some tutorial or sample code ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Locking screens, remote wiping and more are available if you have a mobile device management server(MDM) handy. Check out [this](http://flicksoftware.com/2010/08/mobile-it-guide-to-iphone-deployment-and-management-with-apples-ios-4/) link.

Comment: Thanks Vin for your support and help